# Center container of left floated divs

Tags: html, css

Although a lot of questions are about similar issues, they always want all items centered (which of course can be done using `display:inline-block`), however I need the last line of items to be neatly floated left and only center the container (which is located in a variable container (the body) itself).

[image: Floated divs]

The problem is that no matter what `display` and `clear` I set for the container, it never takes the width of the containing floated elements. I am seriously tempted to think that this should be incredibly simple, but I can't figure out how to get it working.

[Here is a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/4/) to play around with.

Comment: Like in the image, I want them floated *not* centered with inline block, which every single other question is asking about.

Comment: No, the container in which it has to be centered is a variable width body.

Comment: In that case you should setup a better fiddle and add it to your question.

Comment: just put a centered wrapper container with margin:0 auto; and the inner elements just floated.

Comment: That only works if the width is defined, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @PeeHaa: So because you misinterpreted a question, you are now voting to close it? I am quite specific in what I need even showing what I want in an image and preparing a jsfiddle as a basis to try anything out before answering (and if you would have checked the fiddle it would also have been obvious that I was talking about a variable width body, as I commented that the width only was fixed for testing purposes).

Comment: In most designs it is not a problem to set the body to a width of 100% to have a defined width. If you have a special case where that is not possible then you will need to use javascript to compute the sizes on the fly

Comment: @PeeHaa: "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" is not the same as "not all information is in the question". And I never claimed you dv'ed, I mentioned "voting to close".

Comment: @SvenBieder: I am not sure how you would suggest doing this. Could you please be more specific or show me in the jsfiddle how you would propose doing this? (And yeah, I am was already considering doing it with javascript, but I can't believe this to be necessary)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use an inner div for your solution:

CSS:

```
#inner{
    width:396px; /* (100+15*2+2) * 3 */
    margin:auto;
}
```

HMTL:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="block">1</div>
        <div class="block">2</div>
         <div class="block">3</div>
         <div class="block">4</div>
         <div class="block">5</div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/5/) and [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/12/) without fixed body width.

**UPD:** just noticed that you don't want your body width to be fixed. Use `width:80%;` then instead. [*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/9/)

Comment: Use max-width to stop the horizonal scrollbar on narrow width. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/6/)

Comment: @flem, I'd better use percentage for width in this case then: `width:80%`. Otherwise it's not centered when resized. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/7/)

Comment: you can stop scroll bars without adjusting width's at all simply by using overflow: hidden;

Comment: @JDD, the idea there is to center inner div, but it's barely noticable  with relative width anyways.

Comment: The problem here is that at certain widths the container won't be centered like http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/11/

Comment: @DavidMulder, that is why you should dynamically calculate width of a desired row of your blocks and set inner div's width accordingly. In your question your blocks have fixed width and you wanted your second row of two items to be aligned left, so calculated width of your first row is 396px. [Looks centered to me](http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/12/)

Comment: Well, in reality with the exception of the blocks itself everything is dynamic (including the number of items on a row)... oh well, javascript it is.

Comment: Well your problem was: *So the 'goal' is for the 5 blocks to be moved to the right so that they are **together** centered (so block 4 is still below 1).* And styles for your blocks have fixed width both in CSS and in your images. It looks like you're trying to add more requirements to your original question, making it a completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need 2 divs to center this correctly then a set width div to contain all the blocks. Then you can clear it and use the inner inner div (called 'content' in my code here) to control the beginning of the inner float.

Updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h9H8w/8/

```
// HTML
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
         <div id="content">
             <div class="block">1</div>
             <div class="block">2</div>
             <div class="block">3</div>
             <div class="block">4</div>
             <div class="block">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​

// CSS
body{
    width: 100%;
}
#container{
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    left: 50%;
}
#inner{
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    left: -50%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#content{width: 500px;}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
.block{
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin: 15px;

}​
```

Comment: I guess I really didn't explain the question well enough :( The problem is that in your example the div's aren't centered. The spacing on the right side of the container element is greater than on the left side... thus they aren't centered overall neither (this is the state I currently have my code in).

Comment: So you would only need to repeat the process in the #container and #inner again to yet more inner divs to center the group of floated columns.